# eclipse juno can't "Sign In" to google

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I can not "Sign in to Google" from my eclipse Juno install.  Clicking the box on the bottom right panel titled "Sign in to Google" opens a new window.  Sometimes that window has the google login screen, sometimes its blank.  When it does show the login screen, I enter the data and the next screen is blank.

This is on a windows 7 64 bit OS, I have tried the eclipse internal browser, the default system browser, IE and added Chrome (my normal browser).

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Did you ensure you network proxy settings are correct in Windows -> Preference -> General -> Network Connections